# How to change group widget content background color in Qt Style CSS

Tags: css, qtstylesheets

I'm trying to change skin of a program that supports Qt Style CSS, but I don't have access to the source code. I need to change the background color of the groups inside a QWidget, [image]

I tried with:

```
QWidget {
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
}
```

But it changes the color of the whole window, but I can still see the rectangle semi-transparent (like black 95% opacity). What class do I need to edit to change that particular box?

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the style for the class `QWidget` which is the base for any Qt widget.

If you want to change the style for the group only, that's the [`QGroupBox`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgroupbox.html) class.

```
QGroupBox{
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
}
```

Some QSS examples in the doc : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qgroupbox

If you want to set the style on a specific widget of the application you will need more information from the code.